# Как избавиться от ошибок ALSA в контейнере docker?

Tags: docker, alsa

Образ докер был собран со следующими файлами:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /usr/radio
COPY . /usr/radio
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y 
RUN apt-get -y install mplayer
RUN apt-get -y install lirc
RUN apt-get -y install pulseaudio
WORKDIR /usr/radio
CMD ["./script.sh"]
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((; ;)); 
do
  sleep 5
done
```

radio.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

OpenRadio () {
  echo "Выбран канал: $1" ;
  mplayer -nocache -softvol $2 ;
}

case $1 in
  1)
    OpenRadio "Record Remix" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/rmx_320" ;
    ;;
  2)
    OpenRadio "Radio Record Breaks" "http://online.radiorecord.ru:8102/brks_128" ;
    ;;
  3)
    OpenRadio "Radio Record" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/rr_320" ;
    ;;
  4)
    OpenRadio "Future House" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/fut_320" ;
    ;;
  5)
    OpenRadio "EDM" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/club_320" ;
    ;;
  6)
    OpenRadio "Megamix" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/mix_320" ;
    ;;
  7)
    OpenRadio "Gold" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/gold_320" ;
    ;;
  8)
    OpenRadio "Trancemission" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/tm_320" ;
    ;;
  9)
    OpenRadio "Pirate Station" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/ps_320" ;
    ;;
  10)
    OpenRadio "Deep" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/deep_320" ;
    ;;
  11)
    OpenRadio "Vip House" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/vip_320" ;
    ;;
  12)
    OpenRadio "Neurofunk" "http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/neurofunk_320" ;
    ;;
  13)
    OpenRadio "MAXIMUM" "http://icecast.radiomaximum.cdnvideo.ru:8000/max_m.aac" ;
    ;;
  14)
    OpenRadio "Absolutley Country Hits" "http://strm112.1.fm/acountry_mobile_mp3" ;
    ;;
  15)
    OpenRadio "Klik FM Cyprus" "http://eco.onestreaming.com:8310/stream" ;
    ;;
  16)
    OpenRadio "Radio Hersonisos" "http://178.59.22.125:8081/live" ;
    ;;
  17)
    OpenRadio "Birds" "http://sc-brazilianbirds.1.fm:10072/" ;
    ;;
  18)
    OpenRadio "BESTGREEK" "http://bestgreek.info:8292" ;
    ;;
  19)
    OpenRadio "RADIO LEHOVO 971 GREECE" "http://s4.onweb.gr:8468" ;
    ;;
  20)
    OpenRadio "ELLHNIKOS 90.3" "http://live.ellinikos.gr:8010/903.aac" ;
    ;;
  21)
    OpenRadio "Kanali 6 (Cyprus)" "http://stream.dnsgb.net:8012" ;
    ;;
  22)
    OpenRadio "Kanali 7 (Cyprus)" "http://live.kanali7.com:4012" ;
    ;;
  23)
    OpenRadio "Lakka Souli Radio (Greece)" "http://eco.onestreaming.com:8286" ;
    ;;
  24)
    OpenRadio "Sky Radio (Greece)" "http://live.skyradio.gr:9920" ;
    ;;
  25)
    OpenRadio "BeMyRadio Schlager (German)" "http://ns224666.ovh.net:19500" ;
    ;;
  26)
    OpenRadio "Japanimradio" "http://listen.radionomy.com:80/Japanimradio-Webradio/" ;
    ;;
  add)

    echo "данный функционал пока не реализован" ;
    ;;
  play)
    echo "данный функционал пока не реализован" ;
    ;;
  *)  # вызов без аргумента
echo "
============================================================
===== РАДИОПРИЁМНИК ========================================
============================================================
=== Список станций: ========================================
+ 1 - Record Remix : radio 1
+ 2 - Radio Record Breaks : radio 2
+ 3 - Radio Record : radio 3
+ 4 - Future House : radio 4
+ 5 - EDM : radio 5
+ 6 - Megamix : radio 6
+ 7 - Gold : radio 7
+ 8 - Trancemission : radio 8
+ 9 - Pirate Station : radio 9
+ 10 - Deep : radio 10
+ 11 - Vip House : radio 11
+ 12 - Neurofunk : radio 12
+ 13 - MAXIMUM : radio 13
+ 14 - Absolutley Country Hits : radio 14
+ 15 - Klik FM Cyprus : radio 15
+ 16 - Radio Hersonisos : radio 16
+ 17 - Birds : radio 17
+ 18 - BESTGREEK : radio 18
+ 19 - RADIO LEHOVO 971 GREECE : radio 19
+ 20 - ELLHNIKOS 90.3 : radio 20
+ 21 - Kanali 6 (Cyprus) : radio 21
+ 22 - Kanali 7 (Cyprus) : radio 22
+ 23 - Lakka Souli Radio (Greece) : radio 23
+ 24 - Sky Radio (Greece) : radio 24
+ 25 - BeMyRadio Schlager (German) : radio 25
+ 26 - Japanimradio : radio 26
+ play - играть по URL : radio play [url]
+ add - добавить новую станцию : radio add
============================================================
" ;
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

При подключении к контейнеру и запуске скрипта с выбором радиостанции: ./radio.sh 23, появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
Выбран канал: Lakka Souli Radio (Greece)
Creating config file: /root/.mplayer/config
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-9 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing http://eco.onestreaming.com:8286.
Resolving eco.onestreaming.com for AF_INET6...

Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: eco.onestreaming.com
Resolving eco.onestreaming.com for AF_INET...
Connecting to server eco.onestreaming.com[51.195.51.18]: 8286...

Name   : Lakka Souli Radio - Greek Radio - Greece Hellas Radio - www.lakkasouliradio.gr
Genre  : Greek
Website: http://www.lakkasouliradio.gr
Public : yes
Bitrate: 128kbit/s
Cache size set to 0 KBytes
Cannot seek backward in linear streams!
Audio only file format detected.
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [mpg123] MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 320.0 kbit/22.68% (ratio: 40000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [mpg123] afm: mpg123 (MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: No such file or directory
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO SDL] Samplerate: 44100Hz Channels: Stereo Format s16le
[AO SDL] using aalib audio driver.
[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No available audio device
Failed to initialize audio driver 'sdl:aalib'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no sound
Video: no video
```

Подскажите, как установить все необходимые драйвера в контейнер или откуда взять образ ubuntu со всеми драйверами?

Comment: Я думаю, задействуется какая-то аппаратная компонента, поэтому не работает. Ее нужно пробросить. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083436/how-to-play-sound-in-a-docker-container-on-mac-os-yosemite#41084959) это делается, попробуйте

Comment: А еще [вот это](https://comeandtechit.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/failed-to-open-lirc-support-you-will-not-be-able-to-use-your-remote-control/) `echo "nolirc=yes" >> ~/.mplayer/config`. Ошибок в логе достаточно. Фатальная, скорее всего - в девайсе, см выше как его пробросить